# Magnify/de-magnify page text via two buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried in-vain to find a resolution online to my problem. I have two buttons, one a <kbd>+</kbd> sign and the other a <kbd>-</kbd> sign. I would like to allow users when pressing the <kbd>+</kbd> button, to emulate the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> & <kbd>+</kbd> keys being pressed and when pressing the <kbd>-</kbd> button, to emulate the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> & <kbd>-</kbd> keys being pressed.

Any assistance would be so very gratefully received, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand the question but I've used this in the past with success. Check it out: http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  
  var step = 0.2;

  $('.larger').click(function() {
    $('body *').each(function() {
      var actualSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'), 10);
      var newSize = actualSize / 10 + step;
      $(this).css('font-size', newSize+'rem');
    });
  });
  
  $('.smaller').click(function() {
    $('body *').each(function() {
      var actualSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'), 10);
      var newSize = actualSize / 10 - step;
      $(this).css('font-size', newSize+'rem');
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="larger">+</button>
<button class="smaller">-</button>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<p>
  lorem ipsum
</p>
```